# Conditional expectation for linear combinations of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

$X = \frac{ B_1+ B_3 - B_2}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $Y = \frac{B_1 - B_3+ B_2}{\sqrt{2}}$
Where $B_t$ Is brownian motion at time $t\geq0$

I want to find $\mathbb{E} [Y + 3X | X]$

It is known to me that $X, Y$ are independent, and that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] =0$

Is this the correct approach:

$\mathbb{E} [Y + 3X | X]$

$\mathbb{E}[Y|X] + \mathbb{E}[3X|X]$

$\mathbb{E}[Y] + 3\mathbb{E}[X]$

$ =0$

Comment: @Mankind Why the detrimental edit of the title?

Comment: @Did ah, I meant to remove only the part "Check my answer please", but deleted too much. I was on my phone.

Comment: @Mankind Then stop editing while on your phone.

Comment: @did Really? I've done it hundreds of times and have made one mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about the step "$\mathbb{E}[3X|X] = 3\mathbb{E}[X]$" - it isn't true.

It looks like you are thinking that you can remove the conditioning on $X$, but you cannot do this: $\mathbb{E}[X|X]$ is not equal to $\mathbb{E}[X]$, because $X$ is not independent of $X$.

What *does* hold true is that $X$ is measurable with respect to (the sigma algebra generated by) $X$, and so $\mathbb{E}[X|X] = X\mathbb{E}[1|X] = X\mathbb{E}[1] = X$.

Thus $$\mathbb{E}[Y+3X|X] = E[Y]+3E[X|X] = 3X.$$

Comment: Thanks. I should look into this further. But I recognise the property you have used when saying $X$ is $X-measurable$, and removing it out of the expectation operator.

Is there any book on probability which you would recommend, by the way?

Comment: Good. :) I believe that I learned all these conditional expectation results from various notes, so I cannot recommend any book from personal experience. However, I know that Billingsley's book "Probability and Measure" is a standard reference for probability theory, and that this book is widely used everywhere.